# Eye strain due to fluorescent lights

Tags: eyesight, light

I lay on the floor when ever I use my phone. I am supposed to receive direct fluorescent tube light on my eyes. Is there any way to blur or fade the light without reducing the intensity of light ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eyestrain may be caused by flicker rather than by the type of light itself.  Most fluorescent lights flicker at the same rate of your AC power - generally 50 or 60 times per second.  Replacing the ballast with a high-frequency [electronic ballast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_ballast#Electronic_ballasts) will make the flicker undetectable to your eyes.  Modern [compact fluorescent lights are generally in this high frequency range](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/flickering-fallacy-cfl-bulb-headaches/).

If you get eyestrain even with CFLs, then it is probably caused by the color temperature or the intensity of the light, and a high-frequency ballast for a traditional tube isn't likely to help.

Is the reason you are "supposed to receive direct fluorescent tube light" a medical reason?  If so, consult with the same doctor before attempting to fix the eyestrain or you may inadvertently remove the intended benefit.  Find out which components are beneficial (frequency, color temperature, and/or intensity), and then maybe you can alter the remaining traits.

Answer (score 1):

Put on sunglasses ... unless that is considered "reducing the intensity of light". I wasn't sure if you meant "reducing the intensity of light" for other people in the room, or for you.

Answer (score 0):

Cover it with the film used to coat car windows. It will prevent the UV light from reaching and slightly dim it, keeping its intensity.

Comment: I have only black tinted film, doing so makes light emit grey color.